# why the_author() doesn't working

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am learning WordPress theme development and I have developed a theme. All work has been done, but the author name not displaying in a blog page. I used the following:

```
<?php the_author(); ?>
```

but it is not working. Is it necessary to do any function or code in functions.php?

Comment: You haven't shown any code in that post?

Comment: We could do with some code...

Comment: <?php the_author(); ?>

Comment: Are you using that within [the loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)?

Comment: no. what will be the code with loop?

Comment: Check out the Codex page for the_author().  It specifically states:  **This tag must be used within The Loop.**  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author

Comment: @RiponShah - it would serve you well to mark the answer below as correct to improve your acceptance rating.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this is the loop of a page in wordpress:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

   some wordrpess code 

<?php endif; ?>
```

You have to enter the get request INTO the loop, something like this:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

   <?php $author = get_the_author(); ?> 
   or
   <?php the_author(); ?> 

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score -2):

If not within the loop you can try this

```
<?php the_author_meta( 'display_name', $userID ); ?>
```

From [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_meta)